# Finding the $\liminf_{n\to\infty} \ f_n$ where $f_n = \mathbb{1}_{[n,n+1]}$?

Tags: limsup-and-liminf

I am trying to find: $$\liminf_{n\to\infty} \ f_n$$

where $f_n = \mathbb{1}_{[n,n+1]}$ is the indicator function that takes value $1$ in the set $[n,n+1]$ and $0$ elsewhere. It seems intuitively obvious to me that the liminf should be zero. However, when I picture the graph of $f_n$, it seems that for $n \geq 1$, it is just a horizontal line at $1$ that goes off to infinity. Can anyone tell me what I am missing here? Thanks!

Comment: So the domain of $f_n$ is $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Solitary yes it is.

Comment: I get you mean $\liminf_{n\to \infty}f_n$, am I right?

Comment: @JohnZHANG  It is not the limit of the inf of $f_n$, but the liminf of the sequence.

Comment: @RustyStatistician  I don't agree with your image of the graph of $f_n$

Comment: I definitely could be wrong @uniquesolution

Comment: The graph of $f_n$ does not go off to infinity. It hovers above an interval of length $1$, and then it is zero everywhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **any fixed** $x$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $N > x$ so that $I_{[n, n + 1]}(x) = 0$ for **all** $n > N$. So in fact the statement can be strengthened as 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = 0,$$
which of course implies that $\liminf_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = 0$.

Comment: fixed fixed?  I think there is a typo there

Comment: Yes, I meant $x$.

Comment: This is hardly a hint.

Comment: Where is the hardness?

Comment: In that there is a difference between a full, detailed answer and a hint, no?

Comment: Oh, you mean the hint is too complete?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: I think a complete answer still needs some words to justify $\lim f_n(x) = 0$. Or may be I will just delete **Hint**...

Comment: @uniquesolution Care to weigh in on this question?  http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/180618/95564  The stats community doesn't seem have to have the same prowess as you guys do for these types of problems.

Comment: Same with you Solitary :)

Answer (score 1):

A more general way to see it. Let $A_n$ a sequence of subsets of $X$. Define $$\liminf_{n\to\infty} A_n:=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\bigcap_{m\ge n} A_m\\\limsup_{n\to\infty} A_n:=\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}\bigcup_{m\le n} A_m$$

It holds the following caracterization:

$$\liminf_{n\to\infty}A_n=\{x\in X\,:\,x\in A_n\text{ for all }n\text{ sufficiently large}\}\\
\limsup_{n\to\infty}A_n=\{x\in X\,:\,x\in A_n\text{ for infinitely many values of }n\}$$

And, not so surprisingly,

$$1_{\liminf_{n\to\infty} A_n}=\liminf_{n\to\infty}\ 1_{A_n}\\
1_{\limsup_{n\to\infty} A_n}=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\ 1_{A_n}$$

This should help you solve it, and maybe provide you with some insight on the problem. The sequence $[n,n+1]$ is made of sets that "go to infinity": can a real number be definitely contained in them? Can it even be frequently contained in them?

Comment: Care to weigh in on this question?  http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/180618/95564  The stats community doesn't seem have to have the same prowess as you guys do for these types of problems.